# How to test overall significance of interaction terms

Tags: regression, interaction

How can i test (for example in R) the significance of interaction term in this example regression: 
Income = a + b1*Education + b2*White Collar +
b3*Education*White Collar + Error

Education is dummy variable (1=education, 0 no education) and white collar (1=white collar, 0=no white collar). I want to test whether the effect education=1 and white collar=1 combination is different from combination no-education(reference category) and white collar=1. How can i test this when there are main effect coefficient and interaction coefficient? My null hypothesis would be (b1+b3) =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option: `glht` function from `multcomp` package.

Second option: recode `WhiteCollar` to make `1` a reference category. Then, your hypothesis becomes $b_1=0$.

Toy example below:

```
> dt<-data.frame(
+   Education = factor(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0)),
+   WhiteCollar = factor(c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1)),
+   Income = seq(1000,7000,1000)
+ )
> 
> dt
  Education WhiteCollar Income
1         1           0   1000
2         1           0   2000
3         1           1   3000
4         0           1   4000
5         0           0   5000
6         0           1   6000
7         0           1   7000
>
```

First option:

```
> model<-lm(Income~Education*WhiteCollar, data=dt)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = Income ~ Education * WhiteCollar, data = dt)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-5.000e+02  5.000e+02  1.421e-13 -1.667e+03  5.684e-14  3.333e+02  1.333e+03 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)               5000.0     1312.3   3.810   0.0318 *
Education1               -3500.0     1607.3  -2.178   0.1176  
WhiteCollar1               666.7     1515.4   0.440   0.6897  
Education1:WhiteCollar1    833.3     2209.0   0.377   0.7311  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1312 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8155,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.631 
F-statistic: 4.419 on 3 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.1268

> 
> library(multcomp)
> summary(glht(model, linfct = c("Education1 + Education1:WhiteCollar1 = 0")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = Income ~ Education * WhiteCollar, data = dt)

Linear Hypotheses:
                                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
Education1 + Education1:WhiteCollar1 == 0    -2667       1515   -1.76    0.177
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Second option:

```
> model2<-lm(Income~Education*relevel(WhiteCollar,2), data=dt)
> summary(model2)

Call:
lm(formula = Income ~ Education * relevel(WhiteCollar, 2), data = dt)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-5.000e+02  5.000e+02  2.842e-14 -1.667e+03 -8.527e-14  3.333e+02  1.333e+03 

Coefficients:
                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                           5666.7      757.7   7.479  0.00495 **
Education1                           -2666.7     1515.4  -1.760  0.17668   
relevel(WhiteCollar, 2)0              -666.7     1515.4  -0.440  0.68975   
Education1:relevel(WhiteCollar, 2)0   -833.3     2209.0  -0.377  0.73110   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1312 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8155,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.631 
F-statistic: 4.419 on 3 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.1268
```

Comment: Thanks! I once used that second option but forgot it and couldnt find help.